# XCode track variable (SKNode.paused)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, variables, sprite-kit

I am programming a game on XCode's SpriteKit. I have a variable NodeGamePlay (an SKNode) and I set it to `NodeGamePlay.paused=true` when I hit a pause button. I have tracked this through various NSLog statements scattered throughout my code and when I set `NodeGamePlay.paused=true`, the game actually pauses, but it seems to somewhat arbitrarily unpause itself (I don't even have a `NodeGamePlay.paused=false` anywhere in the code).

Anyways, I have not had any success tracking down when this is getting changed incorrectly to `paused=false`. I tried using the "watch variable" feature, to watch the variable NodeGamePlay, but the debug won't stop/alert me that NodeGamePlay switches between true & false. I was wondering if there is some method of tracking THIS property and having the debug stop as soon as the value is changed?

Comment: You need to watch the instance variable `_paused` of the specific `NodeGamePlay` object.

Comment: Thanks Droppy, I'm a beginning programmer, do you mind explaining how exactly I would do this?

PS: In the bottom debug variable window I added an expression "NodeGamePlay.paused", which it understands is a boolean, but it gives me an error "failed to create watchpoint for NodeGamePlay.paused"; any thoughts?

Comment: Break at a place where you can see the object and expand the variables until you can see the `_block` instance variable and then add a watchpoint (right-click).

Comment: Yeah `.paused` is the getter/setter; you need to use the backing instance variable.

Comment: Also try the quicklook add-on so you can actually see SK class properties (and ivars, even private ones): https://github.com/KoboldKit/SpriteKit-QuickLook

Answer (score 0):

Setting .paused == TRUE on children nodes in Sprite Kit produces some odd behavior in my experience, at least in iOS 7, because when a parent node has its .paused set to FALSE, it sets all of its child nodes .paused to FALSE, etc.

So it creates a scenario where you need to override setPaused on your NodeGamePlay class to check a different flag to see if it should allow .paused to be set to FALSE when its parent calls it.

```
-(void)setPaused:(BOOL)paused
{
    if (paused == NO && self.iAmAllowedToUnPauseWhenParentTellsMe == NO) {
        return;
    }

    [super setPaused:paused];

}
```